BAO period of acoustic oscillations
Baryonic Acoustic Oscillations (BAO) is used to analyze the structure of the early universe.  Regions of over density lead to gravitational collapse, followed by a rebound driven by photonic pressure.  This process is usually described as an oscillation, but I have not been able to determine the period of oscillation.  What I have read implies that we see a gravitational collapse, followed by a single rebound, but I don't think that is correct.
So, I am trying to understand how you would determine the period of oscillation for a single baryonic fluctuation.

UCD Physics 156: Dynamics of the Primordial Plasma

Wayne Hu's Tutorial here could be useful. Will try to update later!
